# cannot access private member declared in class

Tags: c++, class, constructor, constructorargument

this is my first question in here :)
i have i little problem..
these are my classes:

```
class Gracz{
    char znak_gracza;
public:
    Gracz();
    Gracz(char znak){
            this->znak_gracza = znak;
        };
    friend void multiplayer();
};
class Osoba: public Gracz{
public:
    Osoba();
    Osoba(char znak){
            this->znak_gracza = znak;
        };
    friend void multiplayer();
};
```

i also have a function multiplayer, where i try tu use constructor with argument:

```
void multiplayer(){
    Osoba gracz1('O');
    Osoba gracz2('X');
...
}
```

but it doesn't work.

errors are same for `gracz1` and `gracz2`

```
error C2248: 'Gracz::znak_gracza' : cannot access private member declared in class 'Gracz'
see declaration of 'Gracz::znak_gracza'
see declaration of 'Gracz'
```

Comment: Well, you can't access the private member `znak_gracza` declared in class `Gracz`. It's private.

Comment: The missing piece to this puzzle may be that `class` members are `private` when not declared otherwise, as is the case with `char znak_gracza`

Comment: `znak_gracza` is a private member therefore it is not accessible in the derived class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constructor needs to pass the parameter to the base class constructor:

```
class Osoba: public Gracz{
public:
    //...
    Osoba(char znak) :
    Gracz(znak) {
    }
```

};

Answer (score 7):

Derived classes cannot access private members of a parent class. You can declare them as `protected` (which is like private but lets derived classes access it), but in your case, since `Gracz` provides a way to initialize the variable, you should just let `Osoba` pass the argument to `Gracz` constructor.

```
Osoba(char znak)
    : Gracz(znak) // initializes parent class
{}
```

Answer (score 5):

`private` member access is only available to members of the class, and friends. what you're looking for it to declare `char znak_gracza` as `protected`, so classes that inherit `Gracz` have access to that member as well.

your class Gracz should look more like this:

```
class Gracz{
protected:
    char znak_gracza;
public:
    Gracz();
    Gracz(char znak){
            this->znak_gracza = znak;
        };
    friend void multiplayer();
};
```

Comment: Isn't it better to delegate to the base constructor?

Answer (score 0):

The `multiplayer` function is a friend of the `Gracz` class, but the `Osoba` class isn't.

Remember that child classes can't automatically access parent classes *private* variables. If you want `Osoba` to access the `znak_gracza` variable you have to make it `protected`.